# How to differentiate between pipe and interactive stdin

Tags: c

So far, I have that if the filename argument (`fname`) is left empty, the program reads `stdin` automatically.

```
if (!strcmp(fname, ""))
    fin = stdin;
```

But I need to know whether that `stdin` was piped in, or interactive, because I could possibly get something like:

```
rsm: reading from (stdin)
^Z
rsm:(stdin):1: not an attribute: `√┘2ç∩'
```

if interactive input was used. Is there some sort of library function I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Posix systems, you can use [`isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
{
    // interactive stdin
}
```

On Windows, you can use the corresponding function [`_isatty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew.aspx).

Comment: POSIX should include MinGW right? How would I do this on Windows?

Comment: @SammiFernandez: Posix is an operating system interface specification. It doesn't include a compiler, let alone MingW. And MingW is just a compiler bundle, it doesn't implement Posix. There are Posix implementations for Windows (Interix, Cygwin), but you should probably find the direct Windows API function that solves this simple problem.

Comment: @SammiFernandez: Try [`_isatty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew.aspx) on Windows.

Comment: I meant MSYS, which would be my primary development platform. And I don't think POSIX includes that either. :/ Thanks.