# Check if the input stream is empty in C

Tags: c, shell, feof

I'm learning C language, I'm having trouble with my program.

So, I have this program called `TEST` this program should allow me to read the argument either with `argv[]` or by using the input stream `$ TEST < argsTest.json`.

```
argsTest.json :
{
"a" = 2,
"b" = 3
}
```

to simplify my question I will use this simple program :

```
Struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} number;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    json_t * root;
    struct number numbers;
    int c = 0, i = 0 , result;
    char str[1024]; // I'm not using malloc just to simplify my question
    // default values
    numbers.a = 0;
    number.b = 0;

    if (argc == 1 && !feof(stdin)) {
        while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
            str[i]=c;
            ++i;
        }
        str[i] = '\0';

        .... // code that use jansson library to extract value

        /** let's suppose we have extracted the two value int json_a
          * and int json_b.
          */

        numbers.a = json_a;
        numbers.b = json_b;

    } else if (argc == 3) {
        scanf("%d", numbers.a);
        scanf("%d", numbers.b);
    }

    result = numbers.a + number.b;
    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

So, I'm trying to implement three behaviors :

1. `$ TEST` it should display `0` ( we used the default values).
2. `$ TEST < argsTest.json` display `5`.
3. `$ TEST 4 3` display `7`.

My problem is that if statement `if (argc == 1 && !feof(stdin))` , actually
`$ TEST` and `$ TEST < argsTest.json` have the same  statement  `argc == 1`, so 
when run `$ TEST` it bug because he enters the first condition.

I want an if statement  that will check if the input stream is empty and having `0` argument, so I can implement the first case without getting in the if statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking the stdin buffer if it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948723/checking-the-stdin-buffer-if-its-empty)

Comment: When you run `TEST`, stdin is not empty. Instead, stdin is whatever you enter on the terminal. You will have to press Ctrl+D for the terminal input to be considered empty. I would strongly encourage you to rethink your interface and work *with* the system instead of against it. Canonical behavior is easier to implement and easier to use.

Comment: @Tim No it's not the same  , it is pretty similar i agree but in his case he read the `EOF` from the buffer so he had to send it with` Ctrl+d` , in my case i want to do it automatically without getting in the if statement . Even if i have to change the if statement.

Comment: @thatotherguy Could you provide me with a small example if possible. like i said i'm pretty new to C prog.language.

Comment: @Haskell-newb How does the computer know whether you're not going to type something, or whether you are going to type something but you haven't yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is

- check `argc` first to see if you should use the values in `argv`
- check whether the terminal is **interactive**

  - if it is then just print 0
  - if it's not interactive then you can read from `stdin`

The problem is that there's no portable way to check if `stdin` is interactive. However, on POSIX systems, you can use the `isatty` function, as [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083069).

So assuming that you are on a POSIX system, the code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct number numbers;

    if (argc == 3)
    {
        if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &numbers.a) == 1 && sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &numbers.b) == 1)
            printf("From argv the answer is %d\n", numbers.a + numbers.b);
        else
            printf("Bad strings in argv\n");
    }
    else if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
    {
        printf("Nothing in argv or on stdin, so the answer is 0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (scanf("%d%d", &numbers.a, &numbers.b) == 2)
            printf("From stdin the answer is %d\n", numbers.a + numbers.b);
        else
            printf("Found junk on stdin\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for those details, i apreciate that very much luckily i'm on a POSIX system.